# Is it possible to do maxpooling on two matrix and change it to single matrix?

Tags: deep-learning, max-pooling

Can I convert two 3x3 matrices into a single 3x3 matrix using a max pooling layer?

For example let's take 2 matrices:

matrix 1

```
1 2 2  
0 1 0           
2 1 1
```

matrix 2

```
1 0 10
1 0 1
0 1 0
```

using maxpool(dim = (2,2), stride =1)

Comment: what do you expect the output matrix to look like?

Comment: a single matrix ,which would be the combine value of the 2 matrix

Comment: if you make your two matrices into samples of your training set, max pooling would do that